# (2d Square Collision Detection) Moving objects apart when they collide stuttering

Tags: c++, 2d, collision-detection, game-physics, collision

I have looked everywhere for some tips on collisions detection but i cant really seem to find anything that makes sense to me or works in my case. I understand how to detect if two square shapes are colliding or not but i dont understand what to do in terms of separating them the correct way with gravity and what not applied to them.

```
if (tile->position.x < other->position.x + Tile::size && tile->position.x + Tile::size > other->position.x &&
            tile->position.y < other->position.y + Tile::size && tile->position.y + Tile::size > other->position.y) {

            glm::vec3 tCenter = tile->getCenter();
            glm::vec3 oCenter = other->getCenter();

            glm::vec3 dir = tCenter - oCenter;

            dir.x = dir.x / (Tile::size / 2.0f);
            dir.y = dir.y / (Tile::size / 2.0f);

            tile->position += dir;
            tile->velocity *= 0.0f;
        }
```

So basically if a collision happens then move them apart. I came up with this method after reading a few things online. This is super close but there is some stuttering that i cant seem to figure.

https://youtu.be/3NJMPDphy3A

Does anyone know what i am missing or can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The video looks nice! This is more of a suggestion, but it was too long for a comment.

There is no rotation or other fancy stuff outside of this code, right? Just gravity, movement, and some bounds check on y=0 (the ground) or similar?

It seems a bit weird that the distance you move each square is proportional to the distance between the squares. Then squares directly on top of each other should not even move. You can sort of see it a few places in the video.

Will you try this and let me know if it is an improvement?

Instead of this:

```
dir.x = dir.x / (Tile::size / 2.0f);
dir.y = dir.y / (Tile::size / 2.0f);

tile->position += dir;
```

Try this:

```
float dmax = max(abs(dir.x), abs(dir.y));
float scaleFactor = Tile::size / dmax;

dir.x *= scaleFactor;
dir.y *= scaleFactor;

tile->position = other->position + dir;
```

And keep

```
tile->velocity *= 0.0f;
```

I don't actually know C++, but I think the code above is valid. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried this and it seemed to work better than the other. There is still a problem with some tiles just gliding over the others until they reach the end of it and fall down or being pushed into the ground or pushed into other tiles. I must be missing something like not checking against the same two tiles more than once if that even makes sense or something else but I have no idea what could be causing this.

Comment: or maybe i need to add more iterations?

Comment: I think the sliding happens because you (presumably) apply gravity which moves the blocks a bit down, and then both our code push them a bit to the side to increase the distance between them. You could add a check, like (If there is a block less than 1.001 tile-size below : do not apply gravity). But this will take a bit more coding. Smaller time-steps will also make it more smooth of course. I don't have anything else off the top of my head :-)